# Unstable Equilibrium of electric force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, electrostatics, charge, equilibrium

$q_1=8q$
$q_2=-2q$

There is a proton at $L$ and $2L$ distance from $q_2$ and $q_1$ respectively. At these distances net force is zero on proton. If we displace proton leftward both forces increases but force due to $q_2$ increases more because $q_2$ is nearer and the proton keep on drifting. I don’t get that. How?
[image]

Comment: Hey here's a few tips to improve your answer and increase the chance of having your question answered. (1) crop and rotate your photos using an image editor like paint or paint.net (2) remove the third image which is a duplicate (3) write equations using Mathjax https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. For example \$Q_1=8q\$ becomes $Q_1=8q$. (4) explain what part you are confused about exactly. Which part of the force increasing is confusing to you?

Comment: Please do not edit questions to ask a completely different question, especially not when you already have received answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Negative charge $(q_1$) is a distance (D) to the left of positive charge $q_2$ which is a distance (L) to the left of the proton. (Or $q_2$ could be negative.)  The magnitudes of the two forces are:  $F_1$ = k$(q_1)e/(D+L)^2$  and $F_2$ = $k(q_2)e/(L^2$). For equality with D = L, $q_1$ = 4$(q_2)$.  If L is changed and D is not, then the rate of change of the forces is: $d(F_1$)/(dL) = -2k$(q_1)$e/(D+L) = -k$(q_1)$e/(L) and $d(F_2)/dL = -2k(q_2)e/L =  -2k[(q_1)e/4]/L$ = - k$(q_1)$e/(2L). $F_1$ is changing more rapidly than $F_2$